# Jasmine test is not detecting that button has been clicked

Tags: html, angularjs, jasmine

I have written a Jasmine test that clicks on the first error message in a list and closes it. It then checks that the number of errors has reduced to the expected amount:

```
it('should close the error if the errors close button is clicked', function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('error in errorList')).then(function(errorList) {
        errorList[0].element(by.id('error0')).then(function(error0) {
            error0.click();
            var arrayLength = errorList.length;
            expect(arrayLength).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```

When I run this I get the message `Expected 2 to equal 1`. 2 is the length of the error array at the start of the test. If I manually recreate this, the error message definitely closes when clicking anywhere within `error0`. Is it possible that clicking this takes some time and this isn't registered by the time the `expect` statement is run?

Here is the relevant part of the HTML:

```
<a class="po-cross-link" href="" ng-click="closeError(error)" id="{{'error'+$index}}">
                    <img class="po-cross" src="\assets\black-cross.png" alt="close">
                </a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please also post the code that handles the click?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are changing the model in the click handler but you expect the DOM elements to be changed instantly. Angular needs a `$digest` cycle to update the DOM according to the model, so I suggest you run `scope.$digest()` after clicking. If you don't have a scope in your test, you can also use the `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...I sussed it shortly after posting. Similar in principle the other answer given I think. It's because I needed to get the most recent version of the DOM. I added in a second asynchronous function as follows:

```
it('should close the error if the errors close button is clicked', function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('error in errorList')).then(function(errorList) {
        errorList[0].element(by.id('error0')).then(function(error0) {
            error0.click();
            element.all(by.repeater('error in errorList')).then(function(errorListNew) {
                var arrayLength = errorListNew.length;
                expect(arrayLength).toEqual(1);
            });
        });
    });
});
```